# Working with the onclick method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and working on exercises. I am just trying to use the onclick and when the FIGHT button is clicked, then the fight function runs. For some reason the fight function is not running but I am able to get the button through DOM.

HTML

```
    <!doctype html>  

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Goal4: Assignment - Duel III</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div id="scores">
        <div id="kabal">
            <p></p>
        </div>

        <div id="kratos">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="fight_box">
        <div id="fight_btn">
            <h4 id="round">Click To Start Fight</h4>
            <a href="#" class="buttonblue">FIGHT!</a>
        </div>
        <div id="fight_bg">
            <img src="images/fight_bg.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript

```
    /* 

    Name: Walker Kinne
    Date: 12/1/13
    Assignment: Goal1: Assignment: Duel1

    */

    (function(){


        console.log('program starts');

        var button = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

        console.log(button);

        button.onclick = function(e){


            fight();

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        };


    function fight(){
        console.log("in the fight function");

            var fighter1 = {name:'Spiderman', damage:20, health: 100};
            var fighter2 = {name:'Batman', damage:20, health: 100};


           var minDamage1 = fighter1.damage * .5;
           var minDamage2 = fighter2.damage * .5;

           var f1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(fighter1.damage - minDamage1)+minDamage1);
           var f2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(fighter2.damage - minDamage2)+minDamage2);

           console.log(fighter1.name);


          // console.log(f1);
           //console.log(f2);



           fighter1.health -=f2;
           fighter2.health -=f1;

           console.log("player1:" + fighter1.health);
           console.log("player2:" + fighter2.health);

            var a = fighter1.health;

    };
           //console.log(playerOneName+":"+playerOneHealth+playerTwoName+":"+playerTwoHealth);
            //var results = winnerCheck();

           //console.log(results);



           /*if(results === "no winner"){
               document.getElementById("kabal").
               //alert(fighter1[0]+":"+fighter1[2]+" ROUND"+round+" OVER"+fighter2[0]+":"+fighter2[2]);

            }else{
               alert(results);
               break;
           }

    */



        /* End of fight function */



    /*
    function winnerCheck(){
        console.log("winner check");
        var result = "no winner";

        if(fighter1[2]<1 && fighter2[2]<1){
            result = "You Both Die";
        }else if(fighter1[2]<1){
            result= fighter2[0] + " wins!!";
        }else if(fighter2[2]<1){
            result = fighter1[0] + " wins!!";
        };

        return result;
    };



    \/******** Program Starts ********/





    })();
```

Comment: @Hardy No, that is totally wrong. `fight` is just fine where it is. A) it is hoisted to the top of the scope, and B) it's not evaluated until the `onclick` handler is invoked, some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`button = document.getElementsByTagName('a');` Returns an *array* of elements. Note the function is called "get *elements* by tag name". To bind an event, you need to work with a *single* element, not an array of elements, even if that array happens to contain only one element.

Instead of this, which adds a property to the array...

```
 button = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 button.onclick = function(e){
```

You need to do this, which adds an `onclick` handler to the first (and only) `a`:

```
 buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 buttons[0].onclick = function(e){
```

Note that, as soon as you add a second link, you're going to need something more specific then `getElementsByTagName`, as your `buttons` array will contain multiple elements. Consider adding unique IDs to the buttons you want to find, and using `getElementById` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a unique identifier to the code opposed to the getElementsByTagName(a) which isn't unique

//this code should help you out

```
            var button = document.getElementById('unique identifier');

    button.onclick = function(e){

               yourFN();
                //dont forget your e.prevent, false info here


            };
```